# Existence of ample divisor with smooth image

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $f:X \rightarrow Y$ be a proper, generically finite morphism between smooth, projective varieties.

Is there an irreducible ample divisor $D$ on $X$ such that $f(D)$ (with the induced reduced scheme structure) is a smooth divisor?

*(Note: originally posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3550323/existence-of-ample-divisor-with-smooth-image))*

Comment: Do you mean f(D) set theoretically?

Comment: @KarlSchwede I think that is what I mean. Is that not equivalent to the current form of the question?

Comment: Sometimes people just mean $f(D)$ as a divisor (in other words throw out any irreducible components of $f(D)$ that are not codimension 1).

Comment: @KarlSchwede I'm going to add the assumption that $D$ is irreducible to the question.

Comment: Do you have any control at all of what you blew up?  Can you assume that $f$ is an isomorphism outside of some non-singular subvariety for instance?

Comment: @KarlSchwede My particular situation is as general as the one in the question. But I'd be interested in any solutions in more special cases (like the one you mention).

Comment: Ok, the reason I ask is that I think if you have $Z$ a smooth subvariety of $Y$, then the general member of the linear system $H^0(X, O(nA) \otimes I_Z) \subseteq H^0(X, O(nA))$ is still nonsingular for $n \gg 0$ assuming $A$ is ample.  This looks pretty close to the linear system you'll get via the pushdown, at least in the birational case.

Comment: @KarlSchwede That is helpful, thank you.